# Latex compilation in Sublime Text

Tags: pdftex, latexmk, sublime-text

Working in Sublime Text in a Latex Document, i wondered.
Is there any way to compile my document look on the right side of my screen? Like Texstudio. 
[image]

Comment: A warm welcome to TeX.SE!  Probably a good thing to read this https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/sublime-text-unofficial-documentation/latest/sublime-text-unofficial-documentation.pdf and I think your question may be answered here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60222/latex-with-sublime-text-2

Comment: Also, I think answered here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111122/sublime-text-3-latextools and many seem happy with this: http://www.latexing.com/

Comment: Do you mean to ask something along the lines of: Is there a way to compile and preview my latex document in Sublime Text?  If so you should clarify your question to more clearly ask that.  If so, I think latexing includes synctex pdf preview.